# how to get poedit working?

Tags: php, poedit

i have followed the instructions in http://www.bunchacode.com/programming/internationalization-and-localization-in-cakephp/

but i keep getting this error
xgettext: language `php' unknown

i have googled like crazy. i cannot find it.

Comment: You are getting this error where...? When opening a file in Poedit? Can you post a sample file? Or on step 6, or where?

Comment: i am getting this error when i update a catalog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this you need to tell xgettext to use PHP as language for your files (when using file extensions like `.phtml` or similar.

In Poedit open the settings, go to the parser tab, select `PHP` and then click edit. In the parser line with xgettext add `--language=PHP` so it looks like this:

```
xgettext --language=PHP --force-po -o %o %C %K %F
```

Maybe you need to add some extensions of PHP files to the extension input field above that occur in your project, for example:

```
*.php;*.phtml
```

This should be enough.

Comment: Still a valid answer. The --language switch is essential for the strings to be picked correctly, and the default poedit setting does not provide it!